# How to pass HTML tags in sendKeys() in selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the below code to input some html related data to a another text area.

[image]

but after that it saves as

```
Table border='1' style='width: 100%;'><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>test</td></tr>
```

It does not begin with 'table' tag properly. Does anyone know how to overcome this issue ?

Comment: On the text area it failed to enter the starting tag alone **<**  ?

Comment: yes Ashok, you are correct